# iTunes - don't know how to moves songs from library to library in same computer

Tags: itunes

I am using iTunes for the first time, and it seems to be very different from Windows OS.

I am trying to do what I would have expected would be a very basic thing - take a song from one library in iTunes and move the song to a different library in iTunes. Everything is on the same computer! I could not find a drag and drop option or a cut and paste option.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! This site works better with just one question at once so I deleted your second question to keep things simple. Please just ask a new question for the second issue.

Comment: Are you moving files between multiple libraries on a single user account (such that you hold Option while loading to choose a library)? Or do you have multiple users on your computer, each with their own user account (and subsequent library)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do. I drag the items from iTunes to a folder, such as one on the Desktop. When you drag items from iTunes, their actual files will copy to a folder or window. I then quit iTunes, launch it again, choose the other library, and drag that folder onto the iTunes window, or to an empty playlist.